# Install4j Input validation expression

Tags: java, validation, input, install4j

in my setup I need some user input. Of course these have to be checked. That works quite well with your "Input validation expression" option.

If the input is valid the Setup is going to the next step as excepted

If the input is not valid, you write that i should display an error message. Since there is no option for error messages on user input I have created one myself with JOptionPane. This also works well, but it jumps every time in the error message - No matter if "next" or "back" is clicked. can not even click cancel without jump into the error screen.

Is there a other way to display the error message? or how do I leave the screen appear only when click on next?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot leave the text field if the input validation returns false.

Another option is to validate the value in the "Validation expression" script of the screen. You can access the value of the text field via its bound variable there:

```
String variableValue = context.getVariable("variableName");
```

For error messages, it is recommend to use

```
Util.showErrorMessage("error message");
```